# dnu build, TeamCity: The type or namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core

I have been trying to get my ASP.NET 5 application to build out to UAT using a PowerShell script.

My solution is laid out like this:

```
+---build
+---lib
|   +---MySubModule
+---src
|   +---Console
|   +---Data
|   +---Domain
|   +---Services
|   +---Web.UI
+---test
    +---Tests.Common
    +---Tests.Data
```

The `build-all.ps1` script lives in `$/Build` and looks like

```
# Build all executable projects in this solution
$thisFolder = (Get-Item -Path ".\" -Verbose).FullName

$projectsToBuild = @(
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $thisFolder "..\test\Tests.Data"));
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $thisFolder "..\src\Console"));
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $thisFolder "..\src\Web.UI"));
)

foreach($project in $projectsToBuild) {
    dnu restore $project
    dnu build $project
}
```

The script works on my machine <sup>TM</sup> but fails on TeamCity with errors like

> D:\Data\TeamCity\Agent2\Work\43f47b78be47a304\test\Tests.Data\MyAwesomeClass.cs(21,26):
>   DNX,Version=v4.5.1 error CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   'IConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

`dnu restore` works and I can see it resolving the path just the same as on my machine yet TeamCity errors?

Why build gods have you foresaken me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By accident, I discovered that `dnu restore` doesn't work recursively for referenced projects.

I had been assuming I could `dnu restore` only the three executable projects and the `Domain` project and other unspecified projects would automatically restore. It works for `dnu build` but this turned out to be a bad assumption.

The fix was to `dnu restore` every single project by using root folders and allow `dnu restore` to recursively scan for `project.json` files.

The amended `build-all.ps1` that works in TeamCity:

```
dnu restore ../src
dnu restore ../test
dnu restore ../lib

$projectsToBuild = @(
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $thisFolder "..\test\Tests.Data"));
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $thisFolder "..\src\Console"));
    [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath((Join-Path $thisFolder "..\src\Web.UI"));
)

foreach($project in $projectsToBuild) {
    dnu build $project
}
```

The actual problem was in `dnu restore` and not `dnu build` as I originally thought.

I figure the reason the script worked on my local was that Visual Studio was automagically restoring packages for the projects in the solution.